# Can I supply 3.3V to a 4V stepper motor?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, pcb, motor, voltage-regulator

I am making a stepper motor driver. The motor requires 4V but the STM32F103 chip I am using requires 3.3V. I am using a DC-DC buck converter to convert the 12V input. Can I supply the motor with a 3.3V voltage for simplicity or do I need two separate buck converters: a 4V for the motor and a 3.3V for the STM32?

Comment: Also is there a way to slightly alter the voltage output of a buck converter? My hope for this stepper motor driver is that it can work with a few different motors with the required voltage ranging from 3V to 4V.

Comment: If you use a stepper driver such as the ‎A4988 you can use the 12V directly and the motor performance will be much, much better. You'll get microstepping, direct connection to 3.3V logic and you won't pollute your MCU's 3.3V supply with heavy motor currents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try powering the motor from 3.3 V. Nothing is going to get damaged. It will operate at slightly reduced maximum current, and hence torque. With a lower voltage, it won't step quite as quickly. Unless you need the absolute maximum torque and stepping speed, you may find it still works sufficiently well in your application.

Comment: This would be my first approach also.  The keep it simple principle.

Comment: According to Ohm's Law, then a decrease from 4V to 3.3V means a 17.5% reduction in current and therefore torque? Or is the actual reduction in torque something else?

Comment: @LucasJiang  It's either much more complicated than that, with speed, inductance, non-linear drop on controlling semiconductors, etc, or much more simple - try it and does it work well enough? At a slightly lower voltage, nothing is going to get damaged.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I supply the motor with a 3.3V voltage for simplicity

Well, you can but you'll lose torque and maximum speed.

> ... or do I need two separate buck converters: a 4V for the motor and a 3.3V for the STM32?

If 3.3V is needed for only the MCU then you can use a single DC-DC converter for 4V, and use an LDO (low dropout) regulator to get 3.3V from 4V. There are many options available with a dropout voltage of as low as 400 mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJCpii.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>